# Hot Reload breaks WebGL2RenderingContext

Tags: typescript, webpack, webgl, webgl2

I have a `webpack/typescript/webgl2`-setup. I have a class that represents the `WebGL2RenderingContext`, which is shown below:

```
import { isNullOrUndefined } from "util";

export class GraphixContext implements Context<WebGL2RenderingContext> {
  private gl: WebGL2RenderingContext;
  private canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
  private constructor(
    context: WebGL2RenderingContext,
    canvas: HTMLCanvasElement
  ) {
    this.gl = context;
    this.canvas = canvas;
  }

  public getContext(): WebGL2RenderingContext {
    return this.gl;
  }
  public appendCanvas(id: string) {
    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
    this.canvas.id = id;
  }

  public static build(): GraphixContext {
    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");

    if (isNullOrUndefined(gl)) {
      throw new Error("WebGL could not be initialized");
    }
    return new GraphixContext(gl, canvas);
  }
}
```

I start the `webpack-dev-server` with the command

```
`"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack ",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },`
```

When I start typing in `GraphixContext.ts` hot reload gets activated and `webpack` creates a `bundle.js`. However ONLY if I edit the code in `GraphixContext` the following error is shown.

```
  TS2345: Argument of type 'WebGLRenderingContext | CanvasRenderingContext2D' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WebGL2RenderingContext'.
  Type 'WebGLRenderingContext' is missing the following properties from type 'WebGL2RenderingContext': READ_BUFFER, UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, and 347 more.
```

Every other edit in my project works just fine. Has someone an explanation for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is type error.

The problem is whatever type system you're using it thinks `canvas.getContext` can only return either a `WebGLRenderingContext` or `CanvasRenderContext2D` but not a `WebGL2RenderingContext` so when you call the `GraphixContext` constructor it believe `gl` is the wrong type.

Change this

```
 const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
```

to this?

```
 const gl = <WebGL2RenderingContext>canvas.getContext("webgl2");
```

Or fix your definition of `canvas.getContext` so it can return a `WebGL2RenderingContext`

The issue is probably in this area

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b7d7d5f7b39a5b9619c77590e5fe7f434ed68f1e/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L5998

There's no entry for `"webgl2"`